# Unable to initialize data member of generic type

Tags: java, class, templates, generics, initialization

```
class A <T>{
T a;

A(){
    a=89l;//error: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to T
}
    
}
public class Main extends Exception{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

why it is giving me error i did all things syntactically

Comment: T is a generic type parameter. It's decided by whatever code instantiates A. If someone creates an `A<String>` or `A<List>` then the field `a` will not be a number field, so trying to set it to 89L does not make sense. If you want `a` to be a long, don't declare it as a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: You may only assign expressions that whose type is `T` to `a`.

89L is an expression of type `long`. T can be anything. Therefore, `89L`, or for that matter, **any expression at all** cannot possibly be of type T unless you already *have* an expression of type T.

This works, and is in fact the *only* way to obtain an expression of type T:

```
class A<T> {
  T a;

  A(T in) {
   this.a = in;
  }
}
```

You need to obtain an expression of type T from a caller or from something the caller provides. Could also be, say, a `Supplier<T>` or a `List<T>` or even a `List<? extends T>` - but one way or another you need the caller to give you something so you can get a T, because you can't make one on your own.

Generics serve to link things. Generics lets you state: "I have no idea what T might be, but I want to write a method where the parameter's type is the same as the return type". In other words, when you use generics, you must use them in **at least** 2 places: As it serves to link types in different places, using them once is completely useless. In your example, you use it only once, which makes generics useless.

In other words, you appear to not understand what generics are for, that's your underlying problem here. If you want to assign a long value to the `a` field regardless of what the user of your class might wish to do, then your field should simply be declared as `private long a;`, not as `private T a;`.